# Input type file js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

При выборе определенного файла, содержимое тега input type="file" меняется на название этого файла.Подскажите, как с помощью JS(JQuery), заменить то, что находится в теге label, на название выбранного файла?

```
<input class="input-form-items file-input" type="file" name="file" id="file" />                   
<label class="input-label" for="file">Прикрепить фото/видео</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let input = document.querySelector("input");
let label = document.querySelector("label");

input.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
  label.innerHTML = event.target.files[0].name;
});
```

```html
<input class="input-form-items file-input" type="file" name="file" id="file" />                   
<label class="input-label" for="file">Прикрепить фото/видео</label>
```

Тут еще будет уместно вспомнить о баге в хроме (до сих пор не пофикшенном), из-за которого при выводе `event.target.files` в консоль вам будет показываться, что объект пустой (то есть как будто ничего не выбрано). Приложу ссылку на более подробное описание, если найду. И я не помню, к сожалению, есть ли такая проблема с загрузкой одного файла, или это только касается полей с `multiple`. Но в любом случае, будьте осторожны.

Comment: Спасибо,работает.